# XML editor is not working

Tags: php, xml, editor, fusionpbx

I have installed xml editor of fusionpbx.I have given path `app/edit/index.php?dir=xml` to xml editor menu.
As I run that link,it shows error

```
    "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 
bytes) in /var/www/html/wlmatp/app/edit/filelist.php on line 70".
```

I increased memory limit in php.ini file.But it not works.I increased memory using `ini_set('memory_limit','1024M')` as well.Still It does not works.
Main issue is as i increase memory limit,it shows that error again.So please help me if there is any solution available.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try using .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 1024M
</IfModule>
```

or 
check

```
 echo ini_get('memory_limit');
```